# Change the default encoding for automatic str to unicode conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

When doing the following concatenation:

```
a = u'Hello there '
b = 'pirate ®'
c = a + b # This will raise UnicodeDecodeError
```

in python 2, `'pirate ®'` is automatically converted to `unicode` type through ascii encoding. And since there is a non-ascii unicode sequence (`®`) in the string, it will fail.

Is there a way to change this default encoding to utf8?

Comment: @KobiK that's not what is asked

Comment: Just use unicode strings everywhere and convert str strings from outside world explicitly.

Comment: No can do - I'm starting to use a template library that only accepts `str` type for everything and my code is using `unicode` literals and everything unicode pretty much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, although it's considered a hack. You have to reload `sys`:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

See this blog post for some explanation of the potential issues this raises:
http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/changing-the-python-default-encoding-considered-harmful.html

It may be the only option you have, but you should be aware that it can lead to further problems. Which is why it's not a simple and easy thing to set.

Answer (score 0):

From the Python Unicode Howto:

Ideally, you’d want to be able to write literals in your language’s natural encoding. You could then edit Python source code with your favorite editor which would display the accented characters naturally, and have the right characters used at runtime.

Python supports writing Unicode literals in any encoding, but you have to declare the encoding being used. This is done by including a special comment as either the first or second line of the source file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

u = u'abcdé'
print ord(u[-1])
```

Comment: This isn't really about unicode literals. If you had `x + y`, where x was of `unicode` type and `y` of `str` type, and `y` had a utf8 sequence, `x + y` would raise an exception just the same due to use of default ascii encoding.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. Something like this then?

c = ''.join([(c.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(c, str) else c) for c in [a,b] ])

Comment: See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25658000/319954) which is exactly what I was looking for.